# How to count NaN or missing values in Pandas DataFrame at a particular row level?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

The following is the code I have written to find the null values for each row in the dataset. I am unable to find a way to get the sum of null values for a particular type of row in the first column of the dataset. The first column is "name".

I am asking for help to find the sum of null values for each kind of name.
Thank you

```
for i in range(len(requiredCSV.index)):
    print("Nulls in row ", i , ":" ,  requiredCSV.iloc[i].isnull().sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

By this code, you can find how many nulls in a row.

```
d = dict()
for i in df['name'].unique():
    val = df.query(f"name == '{i}'").isna().sum().sum()
    d[i] = val
print(d)
```

I made an example, here is my dataset:
[image: dataset]
When I run my code, here is the output:
`{'A': 6, 'B': 4, 'C': 1}` 
it gives how many nan values for each kind of row.

Comment: I meant for each kind of row. For example, 'A' is the name of the person, 'A' has many entries. Count the number of entries of 'A' that contain a null value. The same for the rest.

Comment: edited my code. check it. Next time please provide a sample dataset so that we can work on it. Also providing expected output will be helpful.